# Upload a file and then display contents, django

Tags: python, django

I will preface this by noting I'm a python beginner.

I'm trying to build a very simple app where the user uploads an ics file, and upon submit, the file is parsed and the app displays the contents in a legible format.

I'm trying to use FileSystemStorage(), but I can't seem to set it up correctly.

This is what my views.py and template looks like.

```
# views.py

from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
from pytz import UTC


@xframe_options_exempt
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['icsfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['icsfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(icsfile.name, icsfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        g = open(uploaded_file_url, 'rb')
        gcal = Calendar.from_ical(g.read())
        for component in gcal.walk():
            if component.name == "VEVENT":
                summary = component.get('summary')
                description = component.get('description')
                start_time = component.get('dtstart')
                end_time = component.get('dtend')
        g.close()

        return render(request, 'ics_parser/index.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url,
            'summary': summary,
            'description': description,
            'dtstart': dtstart,
            'dtend': dtend,
        })
    return render(request, 'ics_parser/index.html', {})


# index.html

 <div class="ics-formatter"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="file" name="icsfile">
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {% if uploaded_file_url %}
            <p>{{description}}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:
name 'icsfile' is not defined

Comment: You haven't defined the `icsfile` variable. (you really ought to provide the entire traceback!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the file as `myfile`

Try replacing

```
filename = fs.save(icsfile.name, icsfile)
```

With

```
filename = fs.save(myfile.name, icsfile)
```